# What do AX1800, AX3000, etc. mean within Wifi 6 (802.11ax)?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, mesh-networking

I'm looking at 802.11ax (aka WiFi 6) routers for home consumers.

As of the time of this writing, I see terms like `AX1800`, `AX3000`, `AX5300`, `AX10600`, etc. associated with the product description of each router.

For example:

- https://www.linksys.com/us/p/P-MX10600/
- https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/routers/rax40

I can intuit that AX3000 is faster and more expensive than AX1800, but I can't find anything more detailed than marketing descriptions.

Is there any clear IEEE standard or other canonical definition for what `AX*` means? What does it refer to?

If I get, say, 200 Mbps speed from my ISP, how does that translate into what `AX*` tier I should get?

Comment: [It’s more than just model numbers it indicates the speed like WiFi 5 before it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac-2013#Advertised_Speeds)

Comment: @Ramhound: thank you! Can you please make a full answer out of your comment?

Comment: Don’t have the necessary source material to do that

Answer (score 8):

The numbers indicate the cumulative maximum theoretical bandwidth for all the devices in the package.

The Bands Available and their maximum theoretical bandwidths are
2.4 Ghz: 480 Mbps
5 Ghz: 1300 Mbps
6 Ghz: 1300 Mbps [not sure about this]

For a single device:

AX1800
2.4 + 5: 480+1300 ~ 1800 Mbps

AX3000
2.4 + 5 + 5: 480+1300+1300 ~ 3000 Mbps

For Multiple Device packs:
If you get a mesh system that has n devices, then you take the AX Number and divide it by n.

So a Mesh system with 3 devices termed as AX5400 is actually 3 individual AX1800 devices.

Now on Wifi6, if your router supports MIMO and OFDMA [fancy way of saying a router splits the data transfer of one wide band into a certain number of smaller bands simultaneously]

So an AX5400

MIMO 2x2 on 2.4 Ghz ~ 300x2 = 600 Mbps

MIMO 4x4 on 5 Ghz ~ 1200x4 = 4800 Mbps

Sources:
https://www.mwrf.com/markets/article/21846554/understanding-benefits-of-mimo-technology

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> These numbers refer to the maximum bandwidth, in megabits per second, that the routers are capable of, on all bands simultaneously (including 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz bands). So an AX1800 router, should in theory be capable of transmitting and/or receiving up to 1800Mbps.

> These numbers can be misleading. Because devices can only connect to a single band at a time. This means the quoted speeds won't reflect the actual speeds you'll get in reality. For instance, an AC1300 router might only have a maximum bandwidth of 300Mbps on the 2.4Ghz band.

-[Source](https://www.devicedeal.com.au/what-does-ac-ax1800-ax3400-wifi-routers-mean)